# htaccess Rewrite rule exclude files with extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've got the following Rewrite rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php [L]
```

This way I'm preventing Apache to manage 404 errors and redirect to a specific file when the error occurs. When I type a non-existing URI, Apache just redirects to "index.php" as expected. Everything as expected so far. The problem comes when that rule affects files with extensions. First example is "favicon.ico" automatically requested by the browser, calls my "index.php" script too and this means two calls to the same script which is an undesired behaviour. This occurs when I request a non-existing file in HTML tags as well (all are considered the same: HTTP requests in the end).

Is there a way I can exclude files with extensions from the rule?

Example of desired behaviour:

**I want these to be handled by the rule and redirected to index.php (rule already does it)**

```
http://example.com/thisdoesntexist
http://example.com/thisdoesnt/exist
```

**I want these to be handled by Apache's 404 error and not by the rule**

```
http://example.com/favicon.ico
http://example.com/folder/myimage.png
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `http: //example.com/favicon.ico`
and `http: //example.com/folder/myimage.png` are nonexistent files and you want them to be handed by your Error document instead of the rule ,you can exclude them from the rule.

The easiest way to do this is to exclude `.` dot char in regex pattern.  You can use `^([^.]+)$` to match any uri character(s) except the dot.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. This time files are excluded from the rule but now index.php is calling twice. Suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean by "index.php is calling twice"?

Comment: I meant that Rewrite rule was redirecting two times to index.php but it seemed to be a cache issue. I cleared the cache and it works as expected. Thank you very much.